# How to sanitize a stdClass in PHP

Tags: php, json, sanitize

I need to sanitize the values in a JSON file (e.g., a `composer.json` file from github). I `json_decode($file)` converting it to a `stdClass` object. (I need it as an object, not as an array - I am aware of that option).

I need to recursively sanitize all the values which might be objects as well (and maybe the keys too?).

I need to remove any and all "dangerous" characters, etc from the file but would like it to remain multilingual, so was planning to use `filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW)`.

Advice and suggestions please. maybe I'm missing the obvious, but this seems harder than it should.

Comment: sanitization isn't something you can just sprinkle on some data like it's salt. You sanitize for a particular purpose. What is your target? HTML? SQL? CSV? A dangerous char in one context is utterly benign in another.

Comment: I'll be storing the values in a mysql db and then rendering them in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Михаил-М was close. I needed to adjust it slightly to be:

```php
function sanitize($data) {
    foreach ($data as &$value) {
        if (is_scalar($value)) {
            $value = sanitizeValue($value);
            continue;
        }

        $value = sanitize($value);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

of course, this doesn't address the issue of actually sanitizing the data which I did with the `filter_var` method I mentioned above. so I finally solved it with this:

```php
function sanitize($data) {
    foreach ($data as &$value) {
        if (is_scalar($value)) {
            $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
            continue;
        }

        $value = sanitize($value);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object can be iterated by **foreach**:

```php
function sanitize($data) {
    foreach ($data as &$value) {
        if (is_scalar($value)) {
            $value = sanitizeValue($value);
            continue;
        }

        sanitize($value);
    }

    return $data;
}
```